# Importing UI external DOM manipulator to svelte client

Tags: jquery, svelte, sapper

I am not a frontend developer so I hope I use the right terms here.

I am playing with sapper.

I found a free jQuery, Bootstrap html template and migrate it to sapper.

I extracted some code segment to be components and put all the resources under static folder. Actually every thing is working fine.

The problem is I have a repetitive script tag in all of my routes. It seems to me that there is a better way to do this.

```html
<svelte:head>
  <script src="js/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.waypoints.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.flexslider-min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/main.js"></script>
  <!-- FOR IE9 below -->
  <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="js/respond.min.js"></script><![endif]-->
</svelte:head>
```

Please don't tell me I should not use jQuery with sapper. I download templates and I understand the jQuery code is for visual effects.

Answer (score 3):

You can add **jQuery** or other scripts via **npm** by using commands like `npm install jquery`. Or if you prefer **yarn** package manager, by `yarn add jquery`.

Then you can import necessary scripts in your component, by using:

```js
import jQuery from 'jquery';
```

An example of usage on Borat image in `routes/index.svelte` from Sapper template:

```html
<script>
import jQuery from 'jquery';
import { onMount } from 'svelte';

onMount(() => {
    jQuery('img').click(() => {
        console.log('test');
    });
});
</script>
```